# How to Integrate mailjet in laravel project?

Tags: laravel, mailjet

I am currently using sendgrid but trying to Integrate mailjet in laravel project for email sending.

Any thoughts on How can i Integrate mailjet in laravel project ?

Just wanted to know what can be the potential steps to integrate it.

Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what u have tried so far .? have u done any research ?

Comment: Yes i have checked this - https://github.com/mailjet/laravel-mailjet#:~:text=Laravel%20mail%20documentation-,Usage,methods%20available%20in%20the%20MailjetServices.

Comment: then what error u r getting .?

Comment: There are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.
on executing php artisan module:enable mailjet
 command

Comment: Any idea why i am getting this error ?